# TFS 2010 - TF14040 The Folder may not be checked out

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a .NET 4 website in VS2010 stored in a TFS 2010 team project.  I need to add a reference to System.Data.Linq.dll to the website.  I am referencing a LINQ DataContext that is defined in another project and I get build errors saying that I need the reference to System.Data.Linq.  I go up to the "Add Reference" menu option and add it like I would any normal reference, and it even shows up in the Web.config and in the Properties pages for the website... BUT if I build I still get the same error.

So I found a place in my code where I was referencing the LINQ count function and it told me it was invalid because I was missing a reference and it offered to add the reference automatically.  I told it to add the reference automatically and it is at this point that I get the error mentioned in the subject:

**TF14040: The folder $/Folder/Subfolder may not be checked out. No items were checked out**

I've done some research online but I haven't been able to find much.  I saw on a blog that making the folder not readonly fixed the issue for him, but it didn't seem to work for me unless I misunderstood something.

I tried loading up the project from source control onto a fresh computer where that project had never been loaded before and I can reproduce the issue the same way.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See if TFS sidekicks 3.0 (free) helps you troubleshoot the problem
http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

Comment: I tried TFS Sidekicks 3 at your suggestion but I could not find anything that seemed like it would work, though it could be I just missed it.  I looked for anything related to force checkout/take ownership of a folder, that sort of thing, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, but it's a little strange.  I had some build errors that I hadn't fixed yet, also my web.config file used to be for a 3.5 SP1 site and I upgraded the site to 4.0.  Somewhere along the line the build errors and the web.config combined to form this strange weird error that apparently has nothing to do with TFS.

I figured it out by creating a new website and slowly moving over portions of my site to that new site.  Things didn't go totally crazy until I moved over my web.config.  So I went back and updated my web.config file so that it more closely matched the way a .Net 4 web.config should by trimming out a lot of stuff and now things are good and building fine.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, this error also occurs in different circumstances. I had the same error today from the command line when trying to use `tfs checkout SomeFolder /login:user,password`, although this was not within the context of an asp.net app, I'm currently working on [dependency replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415393/dependency-management-with-tfs-2010/6421198#6421198). For me, adding the `/recursive` command worked, like this:

```
tfs checkout SomeFolder /recursive /login:user,password
```

The hint to try that came from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/d3f8312f-91c0-4b1c-adfb-8329243ec6d6/), by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if this is your problem but I've noticed that TFS2010 seems to have some bug somewhere around folder renames/deletes/changes or something. The bugs seem to go away when you check everything in and try again after the folder change has been saved to source control. I have hit this issue a dozen times this week but don't know exactly what the scenarios are. It's quite frustrating.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, in my case I don't have a folder change to check in.  Everything has been checked in and I got a fresh copy to see if that would help, which it did not :(