# Why is selenium producing this error?

Tags: tfs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, json.net

I'm using selenium 2.0.3 (from a nuget package) for some browser tests. Which all work fine on my local maching.

On our TFS build machine I'm getting the following error when a selenium test is run.

```
System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How do I ensure that this assembly is loaded. It isn't referenced in the project but is required by selenium.

**UPDATE**

I don't know what I've done, but it works now.... it's a mystery. Sorry I can't post the solution, I don't know what it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install selenium 2.0.3 and all its dependencies on the build server.

Thanks

M.Radwan

Comment: or you can install the test agents on a lab machine and run the tests on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on managing build-time dependencies here:
[Dependency management with TFS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415393/dependency-management-with-tfs-2010)

You can use the NuGet command line tool to update your dependencies as part of your build process using a simple modification to your *.*proj file.

Answer (score 0):

There is now (as of version 2.2.0) an official NuGet package from the Selenium team, which can be found at [this link](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Selenium.WebDriver). It should contain the correct dependencies. Should you decide to use the .zip file distribution at the [project site](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads), you'll need references to Newtonsoft.Json.Net35.dll from JSON.NET 4.0r2, and Ionic.Zip.Reduced.dll from DotNetZip 1.9.